# Loading value directly in STM8S103F2 controller in the index register XL (Assembly language)

Tags: assembly, stm8

I am using STM8S103F2 controller in assembly language. I want to load directly value in "XL" index register in one instruction and i do not want to affect "XH" register. (Index "x" register is the combination of XH and XL). Other ways to load value in "X" index register:

1. LDW x,#$50
2. LD A,#$10
   LD XL,A

Comment: Doesn't look like you can do that in one instruction.

Comment: Thanks for the reply bro